# Acrescentar um char a cada iteração for no c++

Tags: c++

Como eu faço para a cada laço de um for somar um char a uma palavra, por ex:

tenho a palavra "char" e dentro de um for a cada laço eu quero que seja acrescentado uma letra "h" após o "h" do "char" e no caso ficaria assim
"char" laço1 ---> "chhar"
"chhar" laço2 ---> "chhhar"....
....

Comment: Poste o código que já fez.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você colocou a pergunta sob o *tag* C++, então, vai uma sugestão em c++

Use a classe `string` para facilitar a sua vida. Você podê usá-la com operadores (soma e igualdade), como se usa em artimética (nem todos os operadores são definidos, por isso, não se esqueça de sempre consultar a documentação para ter certeza do que tá fazendo).

Abaixo é um código bem simples que permite incluir 10 'h's, além do original, como em sua sugestão na pergunta:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::string s;

   s = "ch";
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
      s += 'h';
   s += "ar";
   std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Existem muitas soluções possíveis para a pergunta.

Por exemplo, é possível adicionar os caracteres fixos fora do loop e o caracter repetível dentro dele como no código abaixo, o problema do código é que não é protegido, então o númeroDeHs deve ser menor do que 252:

```
char meuChar[255];
meuChar[0] = 'c';
for( int i = 0; i < numeroDeHs; i++ )
{
    meuChar[i+1] = 'h';
}
meuChar[numeroDeHs] = 'a';
meuChar[numeroDeHs+1] = 'r';
```

Comment: isso é um vetor correto? Mas não há como eu fazer esse incremento de letras de outra forma? é porque no exercício que eu estou fazendo estou limitado a usar apenas o que aprendi até agora que são desvios condicionais e estruturas de repetição

Comment: Não sei se entendi bem, no caso a letra que você informar ela tem q ser acrescentada logo após a letra que contém na palavra? Por exemplo a palavra "teste" e você informa a letra "s" a palavra teria que ficar  "tesste" é isso?

Comment: n precisa ser uma letra específica, eu digo no caso de eu querer colocar em uma letra específica da palavra, por exemplo teste, uma repetição de letras "s".

Answer (score 0):

Eu entendi o que você está perguntando e acho que a forma mais simples de ilustrar isso é da seguinte forma:

```
 int main(){
```

int num_linhas = 0, contador = 0;

cout << "Gerador de triângulos" << endl;
  cout << "Digite a quantidade de linhas: " << endl;
  cin >> num_linhas;

for (contador = 1; contador <= num_linhas; contador++){

`cout <<"*"<< endl;
/*e a cada vez que a leitura do "for" for feita, a resposta adicionar um "*" ao lado do "*" anterior*/}}`

Me corrija se eu estiver enganado. Se for o caso, também estou pesquisando uma solução, afinal, meu primeiro contato com programação foi com o python e, como não é uma linguagem fortemente tipada, você pode multiplicar prints de char (coisa que com o C++ não é possível, pelo visto).
Research and Gambiarra time, bora pro Google.